# Another c# reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a csv file where each row is a different type of record. I am parsing the csv and want to store the rows (varied types of records) in various types of custom classes.

At each row i need to instantiate a different class based on the record type.

So taken from other reflection examples, I have the code below;

```
      Type type = Type.GetType("myNamespace." + className);
      object recordclass = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

so i have an object named recordclass of the correct type, but how do I use it?

all I really want to do is access the properties of the class and populate the row data, and then later add to a container class.

I guess im missing something about the runtime nature of reflection. Please help me connect the dots!

Hope that all makes sense!

TIA,
Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the example you give you could cast your object to the actual type you need:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("myNamespace." + className);
object recordclass = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

var record = recordClass as ConcreteRecordType;
if(record != null)
    record.Name = csv["Name"];
```

Alternatively look into using a Factory to return populated record objects:

```
public class RecordFactory
{
    RecordBase ParseCsvRow(string[] columns)
    {
        const int typeDescriminatorColumn = 0;
        switch (columns[typeDescriminatorColumn])
        {
            case "RecordTypeA":
                return new RecordTypeA(columns[1], columns[2], ...);
            case "RecordTypeB":
                return new RecordTypeB(columns[1], columns[2], ...);
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected descriminator: " + columns[typeDescriminatorColumn]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hans, your idea is worth considering too. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store values into your recordclass's property via reflection use this

```
var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
property.SetValue(recordclass,value,null);
```

Comment: Cheers, just what i needed. And im sure ive seen such code snippets before, but didnt have it in the right context so i breezed over it. THX!

Answer (score 0):

If you read the docs, you will see, `Type.GetType` requires a full qualified type name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly you have a file which contains text values for records. Each record is stored in a single line, and the start of each line is an identifier to say which kind of record is to be built.

It is possible to use reflection for this but not really neccessary.  The problem with using reflection is that you need to know all the properties for the different record types in order to access them by name.  At this point, you may as well be working with typed objects but if you are using the a single routine to create all the records (using CreateInstance()) all you have is an untyped object.

Another solution is to have a set of routines each of which take in, say an IEnumerable (the input line split by the comma, excluding the record id) and return an object (or a record, if you have a base record class) and use a factory to select which routine to use for each row.

You register the routines with the factory by some ID (the first field in the record as you are doing is good, it can be the record class name but doesn't have to be) and the iterate through the CSV lines, using the first piece to select the method from the factory and building the record.

Hopefully the example will explain a bit better :? Sorry about the volume of code

The builders in the example just return empty records but populating them from the row pieces should be easy. Another version is to just pass in the row, or a set of rows if a record can cover a number of rows (a but more complicated if the records take in different numbers of rows)

hth, 
Alan.

```
public string[] Input = new[]{
                                    "R1, F1, F2, F3",
                                    "R2, F2, F4",
                                    "R3, F2",
                                    "R3, F2",
                                    "R4, F1, F2, F3, F4"
                                };

public class RecordOne {
}
public class RecordTwo {
}
public class RecordThree {
}
public class RecordFour {
}

public class BuilderFactory {

    public BuilderFactory() {
        Builders = new Dictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<string>, object>>();
    }

    private Dictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<string>, object>> Builders { get; set; }


    public void RegisterBuilder(string name, Func<IEnumerable<string>, object> builder) {
        Builders.Add(name, builder);
    }
    public Func<IEnumerable<string>, object> GetBuilder(string name) {
        return Builders[name];
    }
}


[TestMethod]
public void LoadRecords() {

    var factory = new BuilderFactory();
    factory.RegisterBuilder("R1", BuildRecordOne);
    factory.RegisterBuilder("R2", BuildRecordTwo);
    factory.RegisterBuilder("R3", BuildRecordThree);
    factory.RegisterBuilder("R4", BuildRecordFour);

    var output = Input.Select(line => {
        var pieces = line.Split(',').Select(val => val.Trim());
        var builder = factory.GetBuilder(pieces.First());
        return builder(pieces.Skip(1));
    });


    Assert.IsTrue(new[] {typeof(RecordOne),
                         typeof(RecordTwo),
                         typeof(RecordThree),
                         typeof(RecordThree),
                         typeof(RecordFour)}.SequenceEqual(output.Select(rec => rec.GetType())));

}

private static RecordOne BuildRecordOne(IEnumerable<string> pieces) {
    return new RecordOne();
}

private static RecordTwo BuildRecordTwo(IEnumerable<string> pieces) {
    return new RecordTwo();
}
private static RecordThree BuildRecordThree(IEnumerable<string> pieces) {
   return new RecordThree();
}
private static RecordFour BuildRecordFour(IEnumerable<string> pieces) {
    return new RecordFour();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, I am toying with the idea of rewriting using your factory idea. Thanks again.